# Under what circumstances can a git commit not have exactly one parent commit?

Tags: git

In git, each commit has one or more parent commits, except for the first one created by the first use of `git commit` command.  As far as I know, other commits have exactly one parent commit unless they were created with the `git merge` command.

Are the above the only circumstances in which a git commit does not have exactly one parent commit?  What other reasons might there be for a git commit to not have exactly one parent?

Comment: For what it's worth, you can have any number of root commits.  To start a new branch that will have a root commit as its first new commit, use `git checkout --orphan <branch>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A commit in Git is always a commit. A merge commit can only be distinguished from other commits by looking at the number of parents.

- 0 parents: root commit
- 1 parent: normal commit
- 2 or more parents: merge commit (octopus merge if 3+ parents)

Comment: To be clear, are the root commits and merge commits the *only* commits that can have other than exactly one parent?

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon: yes, that's the only detail that makes them different.